# Encoding Vertex Position into Vertex Colors

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertex-colors

I got a model in -1 to 1 space and I want to encode each vertex position into the the vertex color for future use. There seems to be nothing by default to do that so I will have to use a custom script for that. I have never used scripting in Blender so I am a bit lost on how to access its data etc. and could use some help.

The pseudo code would be something like this:

```
foreach vertex in mesh.vertices
    vertex.color = (vertex.pos * 0.5) + 1
```

Comment: Depending on your purpose, you could just use Cycles UV coordinates fed directly into a shader

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i need it for exporting so i have to bake it into the vertex colors. i also tried to bake a blender render material into vertex colors but while it looks fine in material mode it is wrong after baking

Answer (score 3):

I updated the script to work in 2.8.

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Color, Vector

my_object = bpy.context.active_object.data
vert_list = my_object.vertices
color_map_collection = my_object.vertex_colors

if len(color_map_collection) == 0:
    color_map_collection.new()

color_map = color_map_collection['Col']


i = 0
for poly in my_object.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        loop = my_object.loops[idx]
        v = loop.vertex_index
        x = (vert_list[v].co.x + 1) / 2
        y = (vert_list[v].co.y + 1) / 2
        z = (vert_list[v].co.z + 1) / 2
        t = 0
        final = (x,y,z,t)
        color_map.data[i].color = final
        i += 1


# set to vertex paint mode to see the result
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
```

part of the solution was from https://blenderscripting.blogspot.com/2013/03/vertex-color-map.html

Answer (score 2):

After quickly scraping together some knowledge about Python and Blender I managed to create a very basic script to do what I want (looks horrible but does its job).

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Color, Vector

my_object = bpy.context.active_object.data
vert_list = my_object.vertices
color_map = my_object.vertex_colors.new()

i = 0
for poly in my_object.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        loop = my_object.loops[idx]
        v = loop.vertex_index
        x = (vert_list[v].co.x + 1) / 2
        y = (vert_list[v].co.y + 1) / 2
        z = (vert_list[v].co.z + 1) / 2

        color_map.data[i].color = Color((x, y, z))
        i += 1
```